# Pip error when using "pip install ..."

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

Using OSX El Capitan. Just installed a bunch of pip module and was following a few online tutorials, must have broken something as now I get the following error whenever I try to use pip (although python seems to run fine).

```
$ pip install pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2837, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 451, in _build_master
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 464, in _build_from_requirements
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

Any helping fixing would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall using easy_install. Close the terminal and reopen. Pip should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pip first by typing `pip install -U pip` and the try `pip install pandas`. I myself use Anaconda/Miniconda. Most of the packages are well handled and the dependencies are taken care of as well by the conda package manager.